# MS Access macro won't output a column in its query to the output text file

Tags: ms-access

In our home-grown MS Access app (Office 365 ProPlus), I added a column to the query which powers our “Export Fixed-Width” macro.  The new column is not getting output to the text file.

It was easy to add a “TransactionType” column to the macro’s specified query, and it returns the correct values it when I run the query separately.
The macro looks pretty vanilla in design view – type is “export fixed width”, table name is the query name, file name is what the output text file is called.

But when I run the macro, or open up the Access app and it runs automatically, type in the start & end dates, it acts normal, shows the “complete” message, but the new column is not output to the text file.
I deleted the existing text file and ran the Access app, and it created a new one, but still without the new column.

It's undoubted something stoopid.

Details about the macro:

```
Warnings On - No
ImportExportText step:----------------
Transfer Type- Export Fixed Width
Specification Name - 1
Table Name - qSecurePay
File Name - \\servername\foldername\accounting\securepay\ARS123123123.txt
Has Field Name - No
HTML table name - blank
Code Page - blank
OpenQuery Step ------------------------
Query Name - qTotals
View - Datasheet
Data Mode - Edit
Export Complete Step ------------------
Message - Export Complete
Beep - No
Type - Information
Title - blank
Set Warnings Step --------------------
WarningsOn - Yes
```

Comment: There is probably an export specification. Please show the full macro.

Comment: Thanks Andre - I've edited the question to include the settings shown in design view for the macro.

Comment: So what does the export Specification specify? Rebuild the Specification - do a manual export and save the Specification.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance... I suspect it is too great for this subject.when the macro is hilited, I type "export" in the Access help box and the only real option is "export selected object to an Access database", but then it wants to browse to an existing database. (cont)

Comment: I suspect my ignorance is too great to make it worthwhile for my time and my company user's purposes and that I should have them do Plan B. When the macro is hilited, I type "export" in the Access help box and the only real option is "export selected object to an Access database", but then it wants to browse to an existing database. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206153/how-to-export-access-2010-data-macros mentions calling a VBA function, but I don't know how to create a place for code or how to call it once there.  Thanks June7.